# Werewolf transforming to human specifics

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

You will get a bounty if you are seen transforming into a werewolf from human.

But what about when you transform back with a witness? Will that still incur a bounty?

Also, if someone is hostile towards your werewolf form, will they still be when you turn back to human in front of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they will still be hostile to you.

No, the bounty will not be applied to your "Human Form" in this situation.

Let me know if i am wrong, but, this is what happens to me.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I remember one time I was running around in werewolf form with J'zargo and accidentally had him turn hostile after I roared. When I went back to human he continued to attack me. I ended up resetting, but I had forgotten about it until now.

Comment: Pick my answer as the correct then :D
Enjoy the game

Comment: @StudentProgramee Welcome to the site! If you've found this answers your question, remember to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark by the answer number.

Comment: Yes thank you, I am well aware of how to use the site. O:-) I was giving others a time to provide a more confident answer with possibly some references

Comment: In fact, I tested the bounty and still received one when transforming back to human with witnesses.